# Watch Folder integrated with a Bash Script

Tags: bash, server, directory, watch

I am currently trying to accomplish three things.

- monitor a watched folder for changes (copied or modified)
- create a log of files that were modified in said folder by users on open directory that are logged into OS X Server
- email the log to specific people in a script.

I have messed around with fswatch / watchdog and trying to pipe commands but nothing is getting the results I need!

Comment: Care to share your attempt(s)?

Comment: I have tried using watchdog, piping different instances of LS and also stat. I know how to most of this except for seeing who the person is that is copying and modifying files and pushing it out into a text. Thank you for the response appreciate any help you have!